# In Spring-Kafka, do we have any listener or interceptor that gets invoked on each retry attempt?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE.And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.

Now my question is,
1. In Spring-Kafka, do we have any listener or interceptor that gets invoked on each retry attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure the container factory with a custom `RetryTemplate` you can add a `RetryListener` to the template.